# Reducing WebLogic Memory Usage

Tags: java, memory, weblogic

I'm trying to run WebLogic in a VM with relatively little RAM.  Is there a way to turn off features or otherwise reduce the memory footprint of WebLogic?  I know I can cap the memory usage, but I'm trying to actually have less memory utilized on average.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of WLS are you installing ?
You can do a custom install of wls and try to select only the components you need.
Reduce the number of connections in connection pool, reduce the number of threads, you have the option to not have wls console itself.

There used to be wls express edition, don't think its there in the more recent versions.

Comment: @SdridharS, where would I have set these custom install options?  I've actually already installed it (WebLogic 12c); can I just modify those settings at this point?  I do want to keep using the console.