# How to start a Weblogic 12c server without J2EE stuff (JMS, etc.)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

Some time ago, I read about a way to start the Weblogic domain in a "thin" version that will not load all the J2EE tools.

Since my app is quite simple, using only JDBC from container configuration will be useful make some tests to verify if we got a better performance.

As far I remember the Weblogic console will simply don't show the configurations on the menu as well.

If anyone can guide me how to produce a domain like that will be great.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are definitely thin clients... but I have never heard of a thin domain. Can you add some more detail to your question?

Comment: As I said, some time ago I see on the web one tip to start the WL Domain without JMS stuff, so that was an option to start a admin console without configurations for great part of J2EE tool not always used. Maybe it  will be  just a java properties on admin and it will get up in a thin way.. but I can't find any on the doc or find the website with this tip again :(

Comment: A slightly similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245842/reducing-weblogic-memory-usage And the answer is correct, when you run `config.sh` to initially create a domain via the GUI, it lists a bunch of optional components you can decide not to install. But I'm not sure that's what you need... Please post if you ever find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the ligher version of WebLogic (without EJB, JMS) add the following option to the command line option startup :

```
-DserverType="wlx"
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!! After that option running all the menu and all "Messaging" stuff (JMS Servers, Store-and-Forward Agents, JMS Modules, Path Services and Bridges) is not loaded/showed :)

Comment: As a official information, from Oracle: Option Description
-DserverType={"wls" | "wlx"}
Specifies the Server Type, which determines the set of services that are started in the server runtime.

The default is "wls", which starts all WebLogic Server services, including EJB, JMS, Connector, Clustering, Deployment, and Management.

The "wlx" option starts a server instance that excludes the following services, making for a lighter weight runtime footprint:

Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB)
Java EE Connecter Architecture (JCA)
Java Message Service (JMS)

Answer (score 0):

The third comment here is totally correct. During install of a new domain you can disable pretty close to everything but the base server.